# Apache Cassandra alternative time series model with many columns in one row

Tags: cassandra, time-series

we are sucessfully using the skinny row aproach for storing time series in cassandra (incl. bucketing). Nevertheless I am looking for efficient storage models for us (e.g. less storage consumption...). One use case is to store **every second** per value to a table.

The last approach (wide row with many columns) feels like an complete anit-pattern for me (Not in theory, but in practice). Has somebody experience with that approach and can confirm my feeling about it?

**1) <s>Skinny Row</s> Wide row (flexible, filtering on timestamp possible)**

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries (
    id int,
    date date,
    timestamp timestamp,    
    value decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, date), timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)
```

**2) Blob/JSON with all values of a day (less storage consumption, no filtering on timestamp on node)**

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries(
    id int,
    date date,
    json text, -- [{'secondOfDay': 0, 'value': 12.34}, {...} or BLOB
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, date))
)
```

**3) <s>Wide Row</s> Skinny row with many columns**

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries(
    id int,
    date date,
    "0" decimal, "1" decimal,"2" decimal, -- ... 86400 decimal values
                   -- each column index is the second of the day
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, date))
)
```

- Inserts on single columns (e.g. insert only some seconds of a day) seem to put the node massively under load. Maybe the full row is loaded before insert?
- but really good storage consumption
- If a row is not filled completely the tombstone warning is triggered: ERROR "Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM ...'" --> this is a no go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I recommend you to use the First Data Model.**

Your first and third data model are similar in cassandra's internal structure. And
Your understanding on wide row and skinny row in cassandra is wrong. The First data model is wide row and Second and Third data model is skinny row.

First Data Model Internal Structure :

```
{"key": "1:2017-06-09",
 "cells": [["2017-06-09 15\\:05+0600:","",1496999149885944],
           ["2017-06-09 15\\:05+0600:value","3",1496999149885944],
           ["2017-06-09 15\\:05+0600:","",1496999146862326],
           ["2017-06-09 15\\:05+0600:value","2",1496999146862326],
           ["2017-06-09 15\\:05+0600:","",1496999142150486],
           ["2017-06-09 15\\:05+0600:value","1",1496999142150486]]},
{"key": "1:2017-06-10",
 "cells": [["2017-06-09 15\\:06+0600:","",1496999171997567],
           ["2017-06-09 15\\:06+0600:value","4",1496999171997567]]}
```

Cassandra store each cell in a partition (`id, date`) key into a single row and Clustering key(`timestamp`) value as key of each cell. That's why this model is called wide row.

So you can see that 1st and 3rd data model is similar. **So you don't have to create new column for each entry of the value, if you use first model instead of 3rd model**

**And don't use the 2nd model, for each insert you have to read the entire value and append the new value and reinsert again. It's a very bad design, an anti-pattern**. And also cassandra recommend a column value to be 1 MB.

> A single column value may not be larger than 2GB; in practice, "single digits of MB" is a more reasonable limit, since there is no streaming or random access of blob values.

Source : https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

If you want to reduce your disk space, you can use the [COMPACT STORAGE](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompactStorage.html) option. The below result show that compact storage reduce disk space up to 35%

[image]

Source : http://blog.librato.com/posts/cassandra-compact-storage

Note :

- Using the WITH COMPACT STORAGE directive prevents you from defining more than one column that is not part of a compound primary key. A compact table with a primary key that is not compound can have multiple columns that are not part of the primary key.
- A compact table that uses a compound primary key must define at least one clustering column. Columns cannot be added nor removed after creation of a compact table. Unless you specify WITH COMPACT STORAGE, CQL creates a table with non-compact storage.
- Collections and static columns cannot be used with COMPACT STORAGE tables.

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompactStorage.html

Comment: great answer, great explaination - thank you for your time.I will continue the test with compact storage.